# Spring, petclinic, Do you want to save this file, or find a program online to open it?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I downloaded the spring mvc petclinic, when I run it, and clicked in the link :

Display all vitiranians

I got a pop up dilog box saying :
Do you want to save this file, or find a program online to open it ?

in the controller that link is defined like this :

```
@RequestMapping("/vets")
public ModelMap vetsHandler() {
    Vets vets = new Vets();
    vets.getVetList().addAll(this.clinic.getVets());
    return new ModelMap(vets);
}
```

My question is :
why it does not dsplay vitiranians and just propmpt me withat dialog box ?
any idea or help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: My question is : why it does not dsplay vitiranians and just propmpt me withat dialog box ?

Comment: maybe the response's Content-Type is not text/html (or similar). can you post the response headers and body (maybe json or xml)

Comment: where is located  the response's Content-Type ?

Comment: Check and compare with your servlet https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/petclinic-servlet.xml

Answer (score 0):

The application to be used to open a content of a certain type can be customized in some browsers (I know only for Mozilla and Opera):

Mozilla Firefox users

1. Open Mozilla Firefox
2. Click Tools and then Options
3. Within the Options window click Applications
4. Select the Content Type you wish to adjust. For example, if you want
   to change how a .PDF file opens in Firefox, select Adobe Acrobat Document.
5. In the Action section, change the action to how you wish to open the
   file. If you want to download .PDF files instead of opening them,
   select Save file.

Opera users

1. Open Opera
2. Click Tools and then Preferences
3. In the Advanced tab click Downloads
4. Locate and highlight the file extension you wish to adjust. For
   example, pdf (or application/pdf). Tip: You can sort these columns.
5. Once highlighted, click the Edit button.
6. Within the file type window, specify how you wish for the file to be
   handled.